# Signing and validating URLs with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am building an API using Flask and I would like to make use of HMAC-signed URLs. However, I am not finding any standard implementations for doing this which work well with Flask's `url_for` mechanism.

Ideally, I would like to be able to support parameters sent both via the request routing functions and via GET query strings, without having to know which is which up-front.

The only library I managed to find for handling URL signing in Python is [Ska](https://pypi.org/project/ska/), which is not suitable for my needs as it wants to handle all of its own query string building. In particular, simply passing a `flask.url_for` URL in results in an invalid URL if that URL already contains a query string:

```
>>> ska.sign_url(url='http://example.com/foo?bar=baz',secret_key='qwerpoiu',auth_user='')
'http://example.com/foo?bar=baz?signature=Fz3fKO3BqD6o4mmMn4EAg9f6pts%3D&auth_user=&valid_until=1561903773.0&extra='
```

(Note the secondary `?`in the resulting URL, which should be a `&`.)

Since Flask already does a perfectly good job of parsing and building URLs, is there a standard pattern for signing and validating URLs produced by Flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is parsing the URL before signing it, and then if there's an existing query string, passing a `suffix` of `'&'` to `ska.sign_url`; for example:

```
ska.sign_url(url=my_url,
             suffix='&' if '?' in my_url else '?',
             **signing_options)
```